# Filtro com operadores do sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Preciso otimizar meu filtro de buscar por descrição, atualmente ele busca resultados que contenham exatamente o mesmo texto que é passado na `query` (exp: "roda liga leve"), e quero que o novo filtro busque por items que contenham as palavras da `query`

**Exemplo:** Busquei por "PNEU 20", caso haja qualquer palavra entre estas na descrição do item salvo no banco de dados, como "PNEU ARO 20", este resultado não é retornado, a pretenção do novo filtro é para que estes dados sejam retornados também.

Vi na documentação do sequelize os operadores `contains`, `contained` e `overlap`, porém, estes funcionam apenas no banco `postgres`, e eu utilizo o `mysql`.

**Código original:**

```
const {
      Company_id,
      IsActive,
      Brand_id,
      limit = 20000,
      page = 1,
      query,
    } = req.query

    let match = {}

    if (!!IsActive) {
      match.IsActive = IsActive
    }

    if (!!Company_id) {
      match.Company_id = Company_id
    }

    if (Brand_id) {
      match.Brand_id = Brand_id
    }

    if (query) {
      match = {
        ...match,
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            Description: {
              [Op.like]: `%${query}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            Code: {
              [Op.like]: `%${query}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            Manufacturer_Ref: {
              [Op.like]: `%${query}%`,
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    }

    const products = await Products.findAndCountAll({
      where: match,
      offset: (page - 1) * limit,
      limit: Number(limit),
      include: [
        {
          association: 'Warranty',
          attributes: ['Code', 'Description', 'Months'],
        },
        {
          association: 'Brands',
          attributes: ['Description'],
        },
        {
          association: 'Families',
          attributes: ['Description'],
        },
      ],
      order: [
        [sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('Products.Code'), 'INTEGER'), 'ASC'],
      ],
    })

    res.setHeader('x-total-count', products.count)
    res.json(products.rows)
```

**Tentativa de alteração:**

No código abaixo, a aplicação está quebrando, pois o retorno do `forEach` está sendo `undefined`, a idéia seria que ele criasse uma linha com `` [Op.like]: `%${element}%` `` para cada item do arrayQuery, o qual contém todas as palavras recebidas no `query`

```
const {
      Company_id,
      IsActive,
      Brand_id,
      limit = 20000,
      page = 1,
      query,
    } = req.query

    let match = {}

    if (!!IsActive) {
      match.IsActive = IsActive
    }

    if (!!Company_id) {
      match.Company_id = Company_id
    }

    if (Brand_id) {
      match.Brand_id = Brand_id
    }

    const arrayQuery = query.split(' ')

    if (query) {
      match = {
        ...match,
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            Description: {
              [Op.and]: [
                await arrayQuery.forEach((element) => {
                  return { 
                    [Op.like]: `%${element}%` 
                  }
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
          {
            Code: {
              [Op.like]: `%${query}%`,
            },
          },
          {
            Manufacturer_Ref: {
              [Op.like]: `%${query}%`,
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    }
    const products = await Products.findAndCountAll({
      where: match,
      offset: (page - 1) * limit,
      limit: Number(limit),
      include: [
        {
          association: 'Warranty',
          attributes: ['Code', 'Description', 'Months'],
        },
        {
          association: 'Brands',
          attributes: ['Description'],
        },
        {
          association: 'Families',
          attributes: ['Description'],
        },
      ],
      order: [
        [sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('Products.Code'), 'INTEGER'), 'ASC'],
      ],
    })

    res.setHeader('x-total-count', products.count)
    res.json(products.rows)
```

OBS: Sou novo no stackoverflow, então peço compreensão e paciência caso haja algum ponto que não tenha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizei uma filtragem manual dos dados, pois não encontrei uma forma de inserir mais atributos na busca com os operadores do sequelize.

```
const products = await Products.findAndCountAll({
  where: match,
  offset: (page - 1) * limit,
  include: [
    {
      association: 'Warranty',
      attributes: ['Code', 'Description', 'Months'],
    },
    {
      association: 'Brands',
      attributes: ['Description'],
    },
    {
      association: 'Families',
      attributes: ['Description'],
    },
  ],
  order: [
    [sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('Products.Code'), 'INTEGER'), 'ASC'],
  ],
})

let prods = products.rows

if (query) {
  const arrayQuery = query.split(' ')
  
  arrayQuery.forEach((word) => {
    prods = prods.filter((item) => {
      if (item.Description.includes(word.toUpperCase())) {
        return item
      }
    })
  })
}

let limitProducts = prods.slice(0, limit)

res.setHeader('x-total-count', products.count)
res.json(limitProducts)
```